# Cómo logro ejecutar el comando “ run lime setup “ y “run openfl setup” de haxeflixel, en una macbook pro m1 Max, sin que me salga error

Tags: c#

Hace poco inicié el proceso de instalación de haxeflixel en mi macbook pro, pero cuando estoy en la parte de ejecutarlo en la terminal, para ver si logré instalarlo todo correctamente, me sale un mensaje de error sobre arquitectura incompatible, y error de directorios. La arquitectura de mi macbook es m1, y la instalación que realicé la hice siguiendo los pasos de la página oficial de haxeflixel, no usé homebrew.

Mensaje de error:

‘’’[Uncaught exception - load.c(237) : Failed to load library: /usr/local/lib/neko/std.ndll (dlopen (/usr/local/lib/neko/std.ndll, 0x0001): tried: '/usr/local/lib/neko/std.ndll' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible]
architecture (have 'x86 64', need 'arm64')), '/Svstem/Volumes/Preboot/Crvptexes/OS/usr/local/lib/neko/std.ndll'(no such file), usr/local/lib/neko/std.ndll'mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have
1×86 641.’’’

Pd: no encontré etiquetas sobre esto.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! obviamente no es c#.. ni siquiera se que es esto.. es un programa de que tipo?